# What extension of chrome enable selective disable image?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

There is a function in adblock of firefox, which enable us to right click on an image and choose to disable the picture. They can also wildcard disable images which under the same level of the blocked image.

I would like this function in chrome too so that I can disable the image easily. Is there any extension I can use? I tried adblock of chrome and it doesn't have that function. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Adblock Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb) has a Easy Create Filter which allows for selective & easy blocking of elements

[image: adblockplus]

Answer (score 0):

There's one call [Blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/epdedalbkhcbhcmcpfglmhngjpgimcmm) . So far, it can block selectively but I realized it's a bit hard to use if you don't mind

Comment: that's a broken link

Answer (score -1):

How about the Google Chrome version of AdBlock?  You can find it [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom).  With over 1 million users, and over 12,000 ratings (avg is 4.5)... I'm sure its just what your looking for.

Comment: Did you read the whole question dude? I tried adblock of chrome already.